# JavaScript Armstrong Number Validator (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following function which takes in an input and validates if that input is an Armstrong number or not:

> An Armstrong Number is a number such that the sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to the number itself. For example, 371 is an Armstrong number since 3 ** 3 + 7 ** 3 + 1 ** 3 = 371.

[Here's a link to the program on codepen](https://codepen.io/Oguntoye/pen/KBJyOB/).

```
const isArmstrong = input => {
  const expandedInputExpression = `
    ${input[0]} ** 3 + ${input[1]} ** 3 +
    ${input[2]} ** 3`;

  const expandedInputValue = Array.from(input)
    .map(digit => digit)
    .reduce((total, currentDigit) => total + currentDigit ** 3, 0);


  if (expandedInputValue === parseInt(input)) {
    console.log(`${input} is an Armstrong number since ${expandedInputExpression} = ${input}`);
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log(`
    ${input} is not an Armstrong number because ${expandedInputExpression}( ${expandedInputValue}) is not equal to ${input}`);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Is there any way to refactor and simplify the function?

Comment: `outputDiv` and outputText are not defined here so this function has an unstated side effect.  Perhaps they should be passed in as an argument.  Also, you've duplicated `outputDiv.classList.remove("closed");` in both arms of an `if/else`.  Can just put it once before or after the `if/else`.

Comment: Also, the name of the function `isArmstrong()` implies it will return a value that tells you whether it is or isn't, but this doesn't do that.

Comment: @jfriend00  Edited to remove unstated side effects and context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in earlier comments, the name `isArmstrong()` implies it will return a boolean value and so other concerns should not be handled by this function.
instead it should be called as an helper in a parent function.

I have refactored and simplified the function as show below:

```
// input logic 
  const processInput = inputString => {

    // isArmstrong() should return a boolean 
    const isArmstrong = stringInt => {
      const digitCubeTotal = Array.from(stringInt)
        .reduce((total, currentDigit) => total + currentDigit ** 3, 0);
      return (digitCubeTotal === +stringInt) ? true : false;
    }

    // output presentation should be delegated to another function
    output(inputString, isArmstrong(inputString));

  };


  // output presentation
  const output = (input, isArmstrong) => {

    const expandedInputExpression = `
      ${input[0]} ** 3 + ${input[1]} ** 3 +
      ${input[2]} ** 3`; 

    if (isArmstrong) {
       console.log(`${input} is an Armstrong number since ${expandedInputExpression} = ${input}`);
    }  else {
       console.log(`
       ${input} is not an Armstrong number because ${expandedInputExpression} is not equal to ${input}`);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Being called `isArmstrong`, it should just return a boolean value, and not have side effects of setting any sort of DOM. That can be done in a separate function by the caller.
2. `expandedInputValue` can probably have a better name. Maybe `digitTotal` or `digitCubeTotal`. But the current name isn't helpful.
3. I *think* this is a no-op: `.map(digit => digit)`

Comment: You're  right on all three points i have refactored the code [>here<](https://codepen.io/Oguntoye/pen/KBJyOB/)  to reflect your suggestions